# remove non-numeric characters in a column (character varying), postgresql (9.3.5)

Tags: postgresql

I need to remove non-numeric characters in a column (character varying) and keep numeric values in postgresql 9.3.5.

Examples:

```
1) "ggg" => ""
2) "3,0 kg" => "3,0"
3) "15 kg." => "15"
4) ...
```

There are a few problems, some values are like:

```
1) "2x3,25" 
2) "96+109" 
3) ...
```

These need to remain as is (i.e when containing non-numeric characters between numeric characters - do nothing).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For modifying strings in PostgreSQL take a look at [The String functions and operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/functions-string.html) section of the documentation. Function `substring(string from pattern)` uses [POSIX regular expressions for pattern matching](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) and works well for removing different characters from your string.
(Note that the `VALUES` clause inside the parentheses is just to provide the example material and you can replace it any `SELECT` statement or table that provides the data):

```
SELECT substring(column1 from '(([0-9]+.*)*[0-9]+)'), column1 FROM
    (VALUES
        ('ggg'),
        ('3,0 kg'),
        ('15 kg.'),
        ('2x3,25'),
        ('96+109')
    ) strings
```

The regular expression explained in parts:

- `[0-9]+` - string has at least one number, example: `'789'`
- `[0-9]+.*` - string has at least one number followed by something, example: `'12smth'`
- `([0-9]+.\*)*` - the string similar to the previous line zero or more times, example: `'12smth22smth'`
- `(([0-9]+.\*)*[0-9]+)` - the string from the previous line zero or more times and at least one number at the end, example: `'12smth22smth345'`

Comment: what's the difference between [0-9]+.* VS. [0-9]+.\* or ([0-9]+.*)* VS. ([0-9]+.\*)*? Test some examples but couldnt find how the back slash plays differently here

Comment: I think the backslash here is redundant (maybe harmful). Point '.' is any character and asterisk '\*' means that character zero or more times. So '.*' means any char zero or more times. Backslash is usually reserved for escaping so that .\\* (point backslash asterisk) means any character followed by asterisk. Can't test on postgresql as I don't have a server currently installed.

Those backslashes might have appeared because when editing text in stackoverflow they need escaping too. For example in your comment the backslashes have disappeared.

Answer (score 67):

Using [regexp_replace](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html) is more simple:

```
# select regexp_replace('test1234test45abc', '[^0-9]+', '', 'g');
 regexp_replace 
----------------
 123445
(1 row)
```

The `^` means `not`, so any character that is *not* in the range `0-9` will be replaced with an empty string, `''`.

The `'g'` is a flag that means all matches will be replaced, not just the first match.

Comment: OK, regexp_replace looks a bit more easy, but how to keep values like "2x3,25" and "96+109" @pensnarik

Comment: but you need to allow the decimal like 34.233 or the value changes completely is there possibility to allow the decimal point ?

Comment: @AbhijitGujar Just use "[^0-9\.]+" as your regex query. that will match any character that is not 0-9 or '.'.